# Head.js multiple cals of head.load

Tags: javascript, head.js

Does multiple calls of head.load syncronised?
I mean if we have code like this:

```
head.load('scr1.js',...,'scr8.js');
head.load('scr11.js',...,'scr18.js');
..................
head.load('scr81.js',...,'scr88.js');
```

Will all this js files loaded asynchronously and executed in order they are in source (i.e scr1,scr2,scr3,....scr8,scr11,scr12...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head.load('scr1.js',...,'scr8.js');` will load files asyn, but execute in order. And similarly `head.load('scr11.js',...,'scr18.js');`. But, its not sure that what block will execute first i.e. `head.load('scr1.js',...,'scr8.js');` or `head.load('scr11.js',...,'scr18.js');`. If you require to execute in order than load your `head.load('scr11.js',...,'scr18.js');` in the callback of `head.load('scr1.js',...,'scr8.js');`

```
head.load('scr1.js',...,'scr8.js', function (){
  head.load('scr11.js',...,'scr18.js');
});
```